# Convert DataTable to Generic List

Tags: c#, list, datatable, generic-list

I have a below method in dataService layer:

```
public  DataTable retTable ()
    {            
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(dt);
            return dt;                       

    }
```

because I should add (using Data) name space in business layer. I wanna change it to:

```
public List<DataTable> retTable()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adap.Fill(dt);
        List<DataTable> lst = new List<DataTable>();
        lst.AddRange(dt);
        return lst ;

    }
```

but I have error in

```
lst.AddRange(dt);
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: You're adding a SINGLE DataTable object, use List.Add()

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a List(of DataTable)? Or do you want a List(Of Rows) extracted from  the DataTable?

Comment: @Steve hmm, I think List(Of Rows) is better! because I want 2D matrix. now what should I do?

Comment: The best approach then is to invest some of your time to implement an ORM tool. You could easily use [Dapper.Dot.Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) (simple, fast and a real lifesaver) or opt for a more complex one (but with more functionality)  like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because table is 2D matrix, so we should return 2D List:

```
public List<List<string >> retListTable()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adap.Fill(dt);

        List<List<string>> lstTable = new List<List<string>>();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            List<string> lstRow = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray )
            {
                lstRow.Add(item.ToString().Replace("\r\n", string.Empty));
            }
            lstTable.Add(lstRow );
        }

        return lstTable ;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This would solve the problem

```
lst.Add(dt);
```

By `AddRange(dt)` you can add a collection of `DataTable`s.

**However `DataSet` itself is a collection of `DataTable`s. Then why reinventing the wheel by using `List`. Simply return `DataSet` like this**

```
public DataSet retSet()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```

Even after you still want to return list you can do

```
public List<DataTable> retTable()
{
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds);
    List<DataTable> lst = new List<DataTable>();
    lst.AddRange(ds.Tables.AsEnumerable());
    return lst;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
public List<DataRow> retTable()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adap.Fill(dt);
    return dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
}
```

but still you need `system.Data` because of `DataRow`

you can use custom class in this case like below

```
List<MyClass> myClass= new List<MyClass>();

myClass = (from DataRow row in dt.Rows

   select new MyClass
   {
       MyProperty1= row["MyColumn1"].ToString(),
       MyProperty2= row["MyColumn12"].ToString()

   }).ToList();
```

and then return this list from our method

Comment: because this method is public, the number of columns and class name is unknown. unfortunately I dont know about lambda codes in generic list. can you give me exact code?